# Attempting to post automatically on facebook (also offline)

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have a challenge in the office. We are developing a script that can post content from our database automatically on the wall. The problem is that we do not have access as soon as the user logs out.

Is there anyone here who has experience with this and possibly have solved it?

We is aware of https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ - Do you think facebook has ruled out the possibility completely?

Comment: To wall of User or to wall of Page?

Comment: are you storing the user's access token?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena: To page

Comment: as long as you have a valid access token, even if the user log's out, you can publish on user's wall.

Comment: @curious_coder: Yes we are storing the access token

Comment: @curious_coder but the access token runs out immediately after log out?

Comment: Have you checked for the validity of the access token using facebook debugger?

Comment: @curious_coder is it possible to set when the time access token shall expire?

Comment: As far as i am aware of nope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the link on how to handle expired access tokens and extend tokens
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using Scenario 5 mentioned on that page you should be fine. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

The page token shouldn't expire.

Comment: Or simply put, use extended access token on `/me/accounts` endpoint to retrieve never expiring Page Access Token